# Keeping the previous highlighting with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a simple table to show the problem I'm having. When a value is highlighted with a checkbox, and if the value exists in the second checkbox it is still highlighted. That's ok. but when I unclick the first or second checkbox, the highlight is gone although it's still in the first checkbox and still clicked. 
Is there a way to keep the highlight on when the second checkbox is unselected?
I hope I made it clear. here is my jsfiddle if you prefer: https://jsfiddle.net/6k5caw8h/19/

Thank you.

Html:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.selector').each(function() {
    $(this).on('click', function(e) {
      check($(this).prop("checked") ? $("#nextColor").val() : '#fff', $(this).attr("name"));
    });
  });
  $('.all').each(function() {
    $(this).on('click', all);
  });

  function all(event) {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      let checked = $("input:checkbox:not(:checked)", $(this).parents('form')).not(this);
      checked.prop("checked", true);
      check($("#nextColor").val(), ...checked.map((i, e) => e.name).get());
    } else {
      let checked = $("input:checkbox(:checked)", $(this).parents('form')).not(this);
      checked.prop("checked", false);
      check('#fff', ...checked.map((i, e) => e.name).get());
    }
  }

  function check(color, ...elements) {
    $('td').each((i, td) => {
      if (elements.includes($(td).text())) $(td).css('background', color);
    });
  }
});
```

```css
table.tb {
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
  margin-left: 200px;
}

.tb td {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="nextColor" type="color" value="#9ac99d">
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="SelectAll" class="all" />SelectAll</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="x" class="selector" />x</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="y" class="selector" />y</label>
</form>

<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="SelectAll" class="all" />SelectAll</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="x" class="selector" />x</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="z" class="selector" />z</label>
</form>
<table class="tb">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>y</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>z</td>
      <td>x</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>q</td>
      <td>a</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. I is invalid to have duplicate ID's on an element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem, where unchecking checkboxes that target the same alphabet seems to ignore the state of the others, comes from this problematic line:

```
check($(this).prop("checked") ? $("#nextColor").val() : '#fff', $(this).attr("name"));
```

In this line, you are simply checking if the specific checkbox that is being clicked is checked, while you should actually check through all your checkboxes with the same `name` attribute and see if *any* of them are checked.

So what you can do is to simply loop through all `.selectors` and filter them by (1) the value of their `name` attribute which matches the current checkbox, and (2) if they are checked. If any of them are checked, the first argument passed into `check()` should be `true`:

```
const $sameNameSelector = $('.selector[name="'+$(this).attr('name')+'"]');
const isAnySameNameSelectorChecked = $sameNameSelector.filter(function() { return this.checked }).length;
check(isAnySameNameSelectorChecked ? $("#nextColor").val() : '#fff', $(this).attr("name"));
```

Update: this does not seem to fix your issue because `all()` is also calling some convoluted logic. All you need is to:

1. Check the `click` event listener on `.selector` to `.change`
2. Simply use the `.all` checkbox to trigger changes to the `.selector` checkboxes and manually fire the `change` event. This causes then individual logic on all the single checkboxes to fire, without needing to duplicate any logic:

```js
function all(event) {
    $(this).closest('form').find('.selector').prop('checked', this.checked).trigger('change');
}
```

Pro-tip: you don't need to do `$('.selector').each({ $(this).on('...'); })` and then bind the event handler. jQuery can handle that intelligently, so you can just do `$('.selector').on(...);'.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.selector').on('change', function(e) {
    const $sameNameSelector = $('.selector[name="' + $(this).attr('name') + '"]');
    const isAnySameNameSelectorChecked = $sameNameSelector.filter(function() {
      return this.checked
    }).length;
    check(isAnySameNameSelectorChecked ? $("#nextColor").val() : '#fff', $(this).attr("name"));
  });
  $('.all').each(function() {
    $(this).on('click', all);
  });

  function all(event) {
    $(this).closest('form').find('.selector').prop('checked', this.checked).trigger('change');
  }

  function check(color, ...elements) {
    $('td').each((i, td) => {
      if (elements.includes($(td).text())) $(td).css('background', color);
    });
  }


});
```

```css
table.tb {
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
  margin-left: 200px;
}

.tb td {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="nextColor" type="color" value="#9ac99d">

<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">

  <label><input type="checkbox" name="SelectAll" class="all" />SelectAll</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="x" class="selector" />x</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="y" class="selector" />y</label>

</form>

<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">

  <label><input type="checkbox" name="SelectAll" class="all" />SelectAll</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="x" class="selector" />x</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="z" class="selector" />z</label>

</form>


<table class="tb">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>y</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>z</td>
      <td>x</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>q</td>
      <td>a</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @Max Sorry, I accidentally hit Ctrl-Z when saving which reverted a change. It should work now (see updated fiddle link).

Comment: @Max I see that it is working: have you checked the latest fiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/pbvq5k4L/9/ Your original issue is that checking two X and then unchecking one causes all the cells with 'x' to be unhighlighted, right?

Comment: @Max Ah, I see that your `all()` method has really complicated logic. I'll update my answer to a one liner. I'll move the code snippet from jsfiddle to my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

To keep the previous highlighting you need to keep a history of the checks someplace and the color that was selected when it was checked. A simple way to do this would be to assign the color data and the timestamp directly to the checkbox.  The following javascript solves the actual problem of maintaining a history so that when checks are removed the color from previous checks are restored.

I refactored the code to do a rendering loop **renderChecks()** which is a more maintainable design pattern.

See: https://jsfiddle.net/c6pt0eb5/1/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.selector').each(function() {
    $(this).on('click', function(e) {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
       $(this).data("color",[$("#nextColor").val(),Date.now()]);
      }
      renderChecks();
    });
  });
  $('.all').each(function() {
    $(this).on('click', all);
  });

  function all(event) {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      let checked = $("input:checkbox", $(this).parents('form')).not(this);
      checked.prop("checked", true);
      checked.data("color",[$("#nextColor").val(),Date.now()]);
    } else {
      let checked = $("input:checkbox(:checked)", $(this).parents('form')).not(this);
      checked.prop("checked", false);      
    }
    renderChecks();
  }

  function renderChecks() {
    const checks = {};
    const names = [];
   $(".selector:checked").each((i,val) => {
       
       if (checks[$(val).attr('name')]) {
          checks[$(val).attr('name')].push($(val).data('color'));           
          checks[$(val).attr('name')].sort((a,b) => a - b);
       } else {
          checks[$(val).attr('name')] = [$(val).data('color')];
          names.push($(val).attr('name'));
       }});
       
       $('td').each((i, td) => {
           $(td).css('background','#fff');
           const text = $(td).text();
           let t = null;
           names.forEach((name) => {               
               if (text.includes(name)) {
                   if (t == null || t < checks[name][0][1]) {
                      t = checks[name][0][1];
                      $(td).css('background', checks[name][0][0]);
                   }
               }
           });                      
       });       
       
  }

});
```

```css
table.tb {
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
  margin-left: 200px;
}

.tb td {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="nextColor" type="color" value="#9ac99d">
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="SelectAll" class="all" />SelectAll</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="x" class="selector" />x</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="y" class="selector" />y</label>
</form>

<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="SelectAll" class="all" />SelectAll</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="x" class="selector" />x</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="z" class="selector" />z</label>
</form>
<table class="tb">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>y</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>z</td>
      <td>x</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>q</td>
      <td>a</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Note: The accepted answer doesn't keep the previous highlighting, it simply keeps the current highlighting.

Comment: Thanks, Ralph. I will check your solution.

Answer (score 1):

I note that the "SelectAll" does not become checked when all the children are checked - I make the assumption that you DO wish to make it "checked" when all the children are checked (a common requirement) so that to uncheck all the children you do not have to check and uncheck the SelectAll.

The other thing is do you wish to keep the related checks checked i.e. when you check "x" do you wish the OTHER "x" to become checked? IF you do, uncomment this line in the code I present here and the like named will check and uncheck in sync:

```
  //  allChecksNotMe.prop("checked", isChecked);
```

OK, now that we are past the checkbox management, lets look at keeping the highlight.  Now that requirement is slightly unclear - you turn them white `#fff` when you uncheck.  Do you wish that or only when ALL are unchecked? Or never turn white; i.e. once with a color they keep it even if unchecked?  My second example has ways to keep the color highlighted when unchecked and to reset to the current color choice as well.

```js
$(function() {
  let cbx = "[type='checkbox']";
  let cbxSel = ".selector" + cbx;
  $(cbxSel) //.add('.all[type="checkbox"]')
    .on('change', function(e) {
      let me = $(this);
      let myname = $(this).attr("name");
      let namesel = "[name='" + myname + "']";
      let allpeer = $(".all" + cbx);
      let allChecksNotMe = $(cbxSel + namesel).not(me);
      let isChecked = this.checked;
      // uncomment to keep like checks in sync
      //  allChecksNotMe.prop("checked", isChecked);
      allpeer.trigger('checkcolor');
      let color = $("#nextColor").val();
      let newColor = isChecked ? color : '#fff';
      check(newColor, myname);
    });
  $('form').on('checkcolor', '.all', function(event) {
    let myForm = $(event.delegateTarget);
    // checks on form
    let formChecks = myForm.find(cbxSel);
    let formChecksChecked = formChecks.filter(':checked');
    let areAllChecked = (formChecks.length == formChecksChecked.length);
    $(this).prop("checked", areAllChecked);
  })
  $('.all' + cbx).on('change', function() {
    let isChecked = this.checked;
    let myForm = $(this).closest('form');
    // checks on form
    myForm.find(cbxSel)
      .prop('checked', isChecked).trigger("change");
  });

  function check(color, ...elements) {
    let newColor = {
      'background-color': color
    };
    $('.tb tbody').find('td').filter(function(index) {
      return elements.includes($(this).text());
    }).css(newColor);
  }
});
```

```css
table.tb {
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
  margin-left: 200px;
}

.tb td {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="nextColor" type="color" value="#9ac99d">
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="SelectAll" class="all" />SelectAll</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="x" class="selector" />x</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="y" class="selector" />y</label>
</form>

<form id="form2" name="form2" method="post" action="">
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="SelectAll" class="all" />SelectAll</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="x" class="selector" />x</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="z" class="selector" />z</label>
</form>
<table class="tb">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>y</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>z</td>
      <td>x</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>q</td>
      <td>a</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Alternate with highlight differences:

```js
$(function() {
  let cbx = "[type='checkbox']";
  let cbxSel = ".selector" + cbx;
  $(cbxSel) //.add('.all[type="checkbox"]')
    .on('change', function(e) {
      let me = $(this);
      let myname = $(this).attr("name");
      let namesel = "[name='" + myname + "']";
      let allpeer = $(".all" + cbx);
      let namedPeers = $(cbxSel + namesel);
      let allChecksNotMe = namedPeers.not(me);
      let isChecked = this.checked;
      // uncomment to keep like checks in sync
      //  allChecksNotMe.prop("checked", isChecked);
      allpeer.trigger('allchecked');
      let anyNamedChecked = !!namedPeers.filter(":checked").length;
      let keep = $('#keepcolor')[0].checked;
      let reset = $('#resetcolor')[0].checked;
      check(anyNamedChecked, myname, keep, reset);
    });
  $('form').on('allchecked', '.all', function(event) {
    let myForm = $(event.delegateTarget);
    // checks on form
    let formChecks = myForm.find(cbxSel);
    let formChecksChecked = formChecks.filter(':checked');
    let areAllChecked = (formChecks.length == formChecksChecked.length);
    $(this).prop("checked", areAllChecked);
  })
  $('.all' + cbx).on('change', function() {
    let isChecked = this.checked;
    let myForm = $(this).closest('form');
    // checks on form
    myForm.find(cbxSel)
      .prop('checked', isChecked).trigger("change");
  });

  function check(anyNamedChecked, myname, keepColor = false, reset = true) {
    let color = $("#nextColor").val();
    let newColor = anyNamedChecked ? color : '#fff';
    let colorCSS = {
      'background-color': newColor
    };
    $('.tb tbody').find('td').filter(function(index) {
      return myname.includes($(this).text());
    }).each(function(index, element) {
      let me = $(element);
      if (keepColor) {
        let scolor = reset ? color : me.data("savecolor");
        if (!!scolor) {
          colorCSS = {
            'background-color': scolor
          };
        }
        me.data("savecolor", !!scolor ? scolor : color);
      }
      $(element).css(colorCSS);
    });
  }
});
```

```css
table.tb {
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
  margin-left: 200px;
}

.tb td {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="nextColor" type="color" value="#9ac99d">
<label><input id="keepcolor" type="checkbox" name="keepcolor" />Keep Color</label>
<label><input id="resetcolor" type="checkbox" name="resetcolor" />Reset Color</label>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="SelectAll" class="all" />SelectAll</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="x" class="selector" />x</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="y" class="selector" />y</label>
</form>

<form id="form2" name="form2" method="post" action="">
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="SelectAll" class="all" />SelectAll</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="x" class="selector" />x</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="z" class="selector" />z</label>
</form>
<table class="tb">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>y</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>z</td>
      <td>x</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>q</td>
      <td>a</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, Mark. this is another great solution. Regarding your questions, yes, I want to check all the values in that row when SelectAll is checked. Each SelectAll has a group of values, and when a particular SelectAll is checked, only the values in this group is to be checked (even though there are other same values). And when a particular SelectAll is unchecked, all the values of that SelectAll turn white (no highlighting). Even though it's possible to check/uncheck values one by one, I only use SelectAll checks here.

Comment: Your answer provides alternative way of doing both. this is a nice touch really. thanks.